# Why does this Android FileOutputStream throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fileoutputstream

There does not seem to be any Android manifest permission that needs to be set for file io.

```
public class Device extends Activity {
    private static final Configuration config = new Configuration();
    ...
    private boolean applyMenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ...
        case R.id.menuSave:
            ...
            configuration.modify(name, to, from, user);
            configuration.write();
            ...

public class Configuration extends Activity {
    private final static String CONFIG = "config.txt";
    private static StringBuilder config = new StringBuilder();
    ...
    public void write() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(CONFIG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(config.toString().getBytes());
            ...
```

Comment: When the write method is invoked?

Comment: write() is in class Configuration (see snippet added to original question) and is called by applyMenuChoice() in class Device when a change is made to the configuration. The debugger was used to verify that configuration is populated as expected before any actual attempt to write, but the exception is thrown before it even attempts the actual write (at the openFileOutput). Is it illegal to use openFileOutput in an applyMenuChoice?

Comment: Your code is very illegal. You can't instantiate an activity (well I guess you can, but you're not supposed to) directly with new(). If you want to write data from one activity inside another activity you will most likely have to pass the data through a service or make another write() method inside Device

Comment: it would be helpful to debug if you can post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Falmarri: thank you very much. This isn't the first time I've done something 'very illegal' in Android/Java. I suppose Configuration doesn't need to be an activity, so when I removed the 'extends Activity,' the NullPointerException is replaced with a FileNotFoundException. The debugger complaint is that this is a "Read-only file system." This is a different issue, so I'll see how far I can get with it.

Comment: Tushar Tarkas: Where can I find the exception stacktrace in the Eclipse/Android debug environment?

Comment: @Falmarri if you move your comment to an answer I'll try to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the illegal instantiation of an activity with correct methods resolved this issue. Thank you very much (again) Falmarri.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to write your file to? If it's on the SD-card of the device, you need to set the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE-permission in your android-manifest. You may also need to set a path instead of just using a filename.

Comment: It is a small file. I am not trying to write to external storage, and I am fairly certain that openFileOutput does not accept file paths.

Comment: I added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest to see if it would help, but it didn't, and I don't understand why this answer is marked as useful if it is not (at least not in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown in this scenario when this pointer is incorrect. You probably created the activity using its ctor like a regular object and not using start activity of an intent. In this case dont invoke openFileOutput or this.openFileOutput , but you should send the context which you are in as an argument to write() function, and use this context, i.e.:

```
write(Context context)
{
     context.openFileOutput(...)
     ...
```